# Stored Procedure in data mining prediction

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a stored procedure to display (fid, name,tel,income,balance,loan_amount, child_count) from two tables 
Family(fid,name,tel,income,good_credit,balance)
Children(cid,name,age,fid). The function should be able to predict who can be a potential customer based on the following criteria:
Good credit, balance>=3000, child_count:total number of children between age 18 and 22, income:40000 and loan_amount = income * 0.3 * child_count

```
      Family table
      fid  name  tel   income  good_credit balance
      1    aaa1  111   15000    1           1000
      2    aaa2  211   25000    0           10000
      3    aaa3  311   80000    0           1000
      4    aaa4  411   40000    1           7000

      Children table
      cid   name    age   fid
      1     bbb1     14    3
      2     bbb2     14    15
      3     bbb3     19    16
      4     bbb4     18    9
```

My code looks like this, but i got an error "subquery returns more than one row"

```
      delimiter $$
      CREATE PROCEDURE procc()
      BEGIN
      declare loan_amount int (200);
      declare child_count int (200);
      set child_count = (select count(age) from Children,Family where age             between 18 and 22 );
      set loan_amount = (select income from Children CV,Family DV where   DV.FID = CV.FID);
      if (child_count is not null) then select cf.FID as FID, cf.Name as         Name, cf.TEL as TEL, cf.income as income, cf.balance as balance, child_count, loan_amount * 0.3 * child_count from Family  cf,Children cc
     where cf.FID = cc.FID and good_credit = 1 and income >= 40000 and       balance = 3000;
     end if;
     end$$
     delimiter ;
```

Comment: Your error is a result of the line `set loan_amount = (select income ...`. The subquery returns more than one row, and are setting it to one scalar variable that can only hold one value. If you think it is an array (`"int (200)"`), it is not. But you are using it in your formula later as a scalar, and `child_count` is already a scalar too, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do there (though I guess it could be a job for a [temporary table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table)), or use the (dependent) subquery directly in your formula.

Comment: okay, i will try that